# Solving the ODE $y^{\prime\prime}(x)-y(x)=g(x)$ using the Fourier transform, without missing solutions

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, convolution, fourier-transform

I'm supposed to solve the ODE $y^{\prime\prime}(x)-y(x)=g(x)$ using the Fourier transform and then explain if I got the most general solution.

First of all, I don't know what "solve" means here because the furthest I can get is $$-\frac{\hat g(\omega)}{1+\omega^2}=\hat y(\omega)$$ which by the convlution theorem tells me $y=-(g\ast \frac 12 e^{-|t|})$ and I don't see what more I can do.

Second, I don't understand what solutions I am missing... Help!

Comment: you mean $\hat{y}(\omega) = -\frac{\hat{g}(\omega)}{1+\omega^2}$. And yes $y(t) = g \ast h(t)$ with $h(t)=- \frac{ e^{-|t|}}{2}$ seems to be the solution.

Comment: @user1952009 cool! Which solutions am I missing?

Comment: note that $h''(t) - h(t) = h \ast (\delta''- \delta) = \delta$ i.e. you've found the inverse filter, aka the [Green function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_function) of your ODE. $\quad$ and note that your ODE was in fact a convolution equation : $$(\delta''-\delta) \ast y = g$$ with the inverse filter $h \ast (\delta''-\delta) = \delta$ you get $h \ast (\delta''-\delta) \ast y = y = h \ast g$ i.e. you solved it

Comment: @user1952009 I have no idea what Green functions are.. I've never studied ODE's properly. Is there a more elementary way to phrase things? This is just a first course in functional analysis.

Comment: it's what I wrote. you have a convolution equation $a \ast y = b$ where $y$ is the unknown, and you have to find the inverse filter $c$ such that $c \ast a = \delta$. when $a$ is a differential filter, $c$ is called the Green function

Answer (score 6):

You have a solution:
$$
                -\frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}g(t)e^{-|t-x|}dt
$$
That solution works for a large class of functions $g$, but it is not the most general solution because you can add solutions of $y''-y=0$. So a more general solution is
$$
           y(x)= A e^{x}+Be^{-x}-\frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}g(t)e^{-|t-x|}dt,
$$
where $A$ and $B$ are arbitrary constants.